# What is the best way to check for nth element in Twig loop?

Tags: twig

So currently the codes below do the following:

- class "custom-border-right-blog" if item is in the first column or second column in a 3 column row
- class "last" if item is the last in the loop.

  ```
  <div class="large-4 medium-12 small-12 columns {% if (loop.index is divisibleby(3) == false) %}custom-border-right-blog{% endif %}{% if loop.last %} last {% endif %}">
  ```

Is there a cleaner way to achieve this? I am quite new to twig and the way I am doing this right now seems rather messy to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [cycle](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/cycle.html) twig function to apply a class according to a modulo. This is really useful when you are applying different classes for `odd` and `even` rows. In your case, this would look like:

```
class="(...) {{ cycle(['custom-border-right-blog', 'custom-border-right-blog', ''], loop.index) }} (...)"
```

Anyway, in your specific case, your way to apply classes looks the best to me.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of shortening the code for better readability i would supoose this one:

```
<div class="large-4 medium-12 small-12 columns {{ (loop.index % 3) ? 'custom-border-right-blog' : 'last' }}">
```

**UPDATE:**

More flexible way in case you really just need the class on the last element:

```
<div class="large-4 medium-12 small-12 columns {{ (loop.last) ? 'last' : 'custom-border-right-blog' }}">
```

Comment: No, he would like to use the `last` class at the very end of his loop iterations; and apply `custom-border-right-blog` every 1-2 items of a 3-column row. That's quite hard to shorten IMHO.

Comment: But that is exactly what my code does... it is a 3 column row so `(loop.index % 3)` would only apply for the last column. Oh well but I switched classes accidently.

Comment: No, as far as I understand, you are putting `last` class every 3 elements; but OP needs to apply his class to the very last element of the array, even if it has more than 3 elements.

Comment: Ok that is correcty... but he explicitly noted that he has three columns. Anyway to make it more flexible just use `loop.last`.